# How to override prometheus by default endpoint /metrics

Tags: java, servlets, prometheus, httpserver

I am trying to expose metrics using prometheus httpserver (io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer) for which i am using below given dependency.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
  <artifactId>simpleclient_httpserver</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Prometheus httpserver by default exposes all the metrics in "/metrics" endpoint and i want to override it and restrict it to expose metrics for any particular endpoint only (like "/prometheusMetrics"). Using below code i running prometheus httpserver and exposing metrics.

```
@ServiceBean(singleton = true)
public class PrometheusCustomHTTPServer {

private static Logger s_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrometheusCustomHTTPServer.class);

private HTTPServer httpServer;
 private static CollectorRegistry registry = CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry;
 private static boolean initailized = false;


@PostConstruct
public void start() {
    if(httpServer == null) {
        String hostAddress;
        try {
            int port = 9090;
            httpServer = new HTTPServer(port,true); 
            s_logger.error("started prometheus at http://"+port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured while starting of prometheus server" + e);
        }
        initialize(registry);
    }
}

private static  synchronized void initialize(CollectorRegistry registryToUse) {
    if(!initailized) {
         new StandardExports().register(registry);
         new MemoryPoolsExports().register(registry); 
          new GarbageCollectorExports().register(registry);
          new ThreadExports().register(registry);
          new ClassLoadingExports().register(registry); 
         System.out.println("StandardExports initialized");
         initailized = true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the client side configuration, but it's not enough. You should also update the **scraping** endpoint of Prometheus "server side" configuration.

Take a look into [Prometheus Configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config):

> > The job name assigned to scraped metrics by default. job_name: <job_name>
>
> # How frequently to scrape targets from this job. [ scrape_interval:  | default = <global_config.scrape_interval> ]
>
> Per-scrape timeout when scraping this job. [ scrape_timeout:  | default = <global_config.scrape_timeout> ]
>
> # The HTTP resource path on which to fetch metrics from targets.
> **[ metrics_path:  | default = /metrics ]**

Comment: Hello @evgenyl Thanks for your response . For this part i am aware that we need to set the endpoint in prometheus.yaml file . But how we can change the default endpoint from client side (java code) from where prometheus pull the metrics and later same i will update in prometheus.yaml file .

As i have seen the source code of HTTPServer from there i am not able to find any way to update new endpoint or even if i want to expose metrics on only one point that part is also not achieveable because metrics are getting exposed in all the paths or endpoints for the configured host and port .

Comment: I am less familiar with Java code for httpserver, but take a look at this example:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer

        httpServer.createContext("/", httpExchange -> {
            if ("/metrics".equals(httpExchange.getRequestURI().getPath())) {
                respondMetrics(registry, httpExchange);
            } else {
                respondRedirect(httpExchange);
            }

Comment: but com.sun.* package can't be used directly in the code it should be used by some api otherwise it throws reference not found error . I tried doing that but it didn't helped.